# groovy jenkins. fileExists function in groovy doesn't see my files

Tags: linux, docker, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

In my container I'm running jenkins job.
In the jenkins job I check if I have python file.

`fileExists('/root/.pyenv/versions/3.7.10/bin/python')`

It returns false.

But when I do ->
`ls -la /root/.pyenv/versions/3.7.10/bin/python`
I can see the file there.

I even checked inside the container and saw the files.

I tried giving chmod 777 in the image file so all files will have the permissions...
But still..
If its not permissions, what else could it be?

I tried using fileExists /root and it does see it. But only this directory, not the files and dirs inside.

Comment: This could be a permissions issue and the methods execute with different users. Remember that your workspace would be bind volume mounted if the container is part of your `agent` directive.

Comment: Can I run the function with the specific user?
How does chmod 777 didn't solve it?

Comment: @MattSchuchard how would you solve it?